# How to append parameter by <href> tag ,which is coming from filter(servlet) automatically in Struts 2?

Tags: java, html, filter, struts2

```
public class URLSessionFilter implements Filter {

        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            String i = url+actionURL;
            System.out.println(i);
            String string = i;
            String[] parts = string.split(Pattern.quote("?"));
            String part1 = parts[0]; // break
            String part2 = parts[1]; //break
            return part1+actionURL;
        }

    };
        chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);   
}
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {   
}
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

this url is get by struts tags easily with append parameter

```
<a href="<s:url action="getKeyTwo"/>">index2</a>
```

but if we use it by simple href it will not append url parameter

```
<a href="getKey5" onclick="location.href=@Url.Action(getKey5)">getKey5</a><br/>
```

please give me suggestion

Comment: Where or what url parameter?

Comment: actionURL (?c7d59c38-5357-4823-b29c-ddc3c49e483a?.action) which is parameter, and it append with encodeURL(String url) is url (getKey4) which is being clicked .  acutaully it makes dynamic url:  <a href="<s:url action="getKey4"/>">index2</a>  showes results (http://localhost:8080/exampleHref/getKey4?c7d59c38-5357-4823-b29c-ddc3c49e483a?.action)

Comment: This url doesn't work.

Comment: actually it works by struts tag  <a href="<s:url action="getKeyTwo"/>">index2</a> ... but i want to get it by (simple html href tag ).. without calling any parameters and any struts tag in href like as above ..

Comment: this should be done by (simple html and calling by just function of struts) ..no struts tags, how will url be generated please help me ??

Comment: isn't it a simple html? also you can't just call a function of struts without ajax.

Comment: alright but i cannot touch any jsp file struts.xml and class . is it possible href tag automatically takes response.encodeurl() by filter ?  and jsp will remain simple  <a href="index5">index5</a><br/>.. any logic in filter ?

Comment: it's very long and difficult way, with struts it's easier, but it requires to have a little knowledge about struts.

Comment: Thank -You Sir for you precious time ^_^  :)  ... i have done it by many ways .. but when i want to try by <a href="index5">index5</a><br/>.. my logic fails because of it ... ! i will have to apply some logic in filter and get url ... !!